# Python List not appending value to list when using function

Tags: python, list, function

I have a function called func() which takes a value n and converts that into a list. I want to append it to a qwert each time i run the function.

The desired output for qwert is : [[3],[4],[5]]

What i am getting is :[]

I am not able to figure out the issue.

```
def func(n):
    global qwert
    qwe=[n]
    qwe.append(qwert)
    print('qwe=')
    print(qwe)
    print('\nqwert=')    
    print(qwert)
    return 1

func(3)
func(4)
func(5)

print (qwert)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was super silly mistake from my side :P

````
def func(n):
    global qwert
    qwe=[n]
    qwert.append(qwe)
    print('qwe=')
    print(qwe)
    print('\nqwert=')    
    print(qwert)
    return 1
func(3)
func(4)
func(5)
print ('\n\nfinal output:')
print (qwert)```
````